# Session Empty when i redirect url in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, session, redirect, session-variables, session-state

My Session goes empty when I redirect the url like this

```
redirect("noticelist/blog","refresh");
```

Before the redirecting, I save the array in user_data(array_variable). When link redirect, this variable is goes empty, this variable hold the info of the username,password,imagepath of the logged in user.

I don't know how to solve this bug. Any help would be appreciated.

Note: I use default session class of codeigniter.

Comment: are you autoloading the session class?  are you using `$this->session->set_userdata('some_name', 'some_value');`

Comment: Yes Andrew i did same......

Answer (score 0):

How does your config file look? - (for the session)
How long is the session supposed to be active?
Is the session okay with other redirects? or is the problem there only?